# How do I call a Grails namedQuery on a particular datasource?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a small Grails application. I have decided to make a multi tenant architecture. I have several dataSources defined in DataSource.groovy.

The problem is I have defined several namedQueries in my Domain Model classes.

Trying to call:

```
Pomelo.one.matchByOneParam("paramValue").list()
```

does not seem to work.

I get

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
No signature of method: Pomelo.matchByOneValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)
```

I understand the error but I need to find a way to call these queries depending on the dataSource.

Is there a correct syntax for this or is this feature not supported yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced this issue a few months back and have not got any working solution, but found [this Grails JIRA](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9749) issue that haven't been resolved yet. And finally I use workaround mentioned in the issue, `createCriteria`.

Comment: thank you. Now I have to decide what to do. I guess I'll go criteria all the way then.